# Bash sending email with Amazon SES: Invalid JSON Control character

Tags: json, bash, amazon-ses

When I try to run the code below to send an email with an attachment, I get the error "INVALID JSON, INVALID CONTROL CHARACTER"

I thought replacing all the `\n` with `\\n` would fix this, but it didn't...

Is the error possibly in the attachment itself?

```
echo '{"Data": "From:'${SENDER}'\\nTo:'${RECIPIENT}'\nSubject:'${SUBJECT}'\\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-type: Multipart/Mixed; boundary=\"NextPart\"\\n\\n--NextPart\\nContent-Type: text/plain\\n\\n'${BODY}'\\n\\n--NextPart\\nContent-Type:'${ATTACHMENT_TYPE}';\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"'${ATTACHMENT_FILE_NAME}'\"\\n\\n'$(cat ./${ATTACHMENT_FILE_TO_READ_FROM_DISK})'\\n--NextPart--"}' > "$tmp_message"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you have not escaped **all** the newlines.
2. I'd recommend you build this up in steps so it's not the unreadable one-liner you have:

   ```bash
   msg=$(cat << END_EMAIL
   From:${SENDER}
   To:${RECIPIENT}
   Subject:${SUBJECT}
   MIME-Version: 1.0
   Content-type: Multipart/Mixed; boundary="NextPart"

   --NextPart
   Content-Type: text/plain

   ${BODY}

   --NextPart
   Content-Type:${ATTACHMENT_TYPE};
   Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="${ATTACHMENT_FILE_NAME}"

   $(cat ./${ATTACHMENT_FILE_TO_READ_FROM_DISK})
   --NextPart--
   END_EMAIL
   )

   json=$(jq -n -c --arg m "$msg" '{Data: $m}')

   do_something_with "$json"
   ```